# Importing ODS to phpmyadmin error 1117: too many columns

Tags: mysql, database, excel, phpmyadmin, ods

so I am currently testing one web application, and for that I need to import an excel file to phpmyadmin.

I need to import the file as an *.ods. To do that, I know I need to rename the file so that it matches the table name, and set values in first row to match columns. However, whenever I try to import the file, I get an error 1117: too many columns, listing all the unecessary empty columns in my ods file (F,G,H,I,J....).

Is there any way to remove those columns, or have them be ignored?

Comment: ODS is not identical with Excel's format, no? What importer are you using and what file formats does it support?

Comment: It is the format that a guy I work with wants to use, and I am using built-in importer in PhpMyAdmin, it supports XML,SQL,CSV,ODS and some other formats, however I need to use this specific one. I think the problem is quite trivial, however I do not know how to limit the column count so that PhpMyAdmin does not try to import all of them, even the blank ones (and I have specified that I do NOT want the empty ones imported).

Comment: A search for `error 1117: too many columns ODS` seems to yield relevant results

Answer (score 0):

A lot of things can wrong when you're importing a spreadsheet.  If your boss highlighted row 70,000 the color "invisible" (yes kids, that's a color now), the row will stretch into infinity and give a too many columns error.  Save as csv and you delete all that mess, but then you have to make sure your delimiters are nice and neat or your fields will wander into their neighbor's columns.